# Results of Merging Two Different Tracking Branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-remote

Imagine I have two branches, one of which has been set up to track one remote-tracking branch and another which has similarly been set up to track a *different* remote-tracking branch.  Now, let's say I merge these two branches together into a single branch.  How would such a merger affect the resulting branch's connectivity?  Would the resulting branch still be able to track both of the remote-tracking branches which were tracked by its un-merged predecessors, or would one remote-tracking branch no longer be tracked by my new, merged branch?

Comment: The exact same thing as when you merge any other two branches.

Answer (score 0):

They get merged. Nothing else happens. Tracking isn't affected by `git merge`. If you made a new branch, not tracking anything, and merged both into it, it still won't be tracking anything. If you merged one branch into another, the branch you merged into will still be tracking the same thing it was before.

Comment: As I clarified above in my original question by editing it, I was _really_ wondering what would happen if you had two branches, each tracking a separate remote, and then merged them together and how such a merger would affect remote connectivity.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel my answer answers that question as well.

Comment: So the resulting branch couldn't have more than one remote?

Comment: See my last comment since I forgot to add a notification for you into it at its beginning….

Comment: @RandomDSdevel correct, a branch only has one remote.

Comment: So there's no way to go through a repository and merge all of its remote-tracking branches together, one by one, such that you end up with a `master` branch that's fetching some files from one remote-tracking branch, some other files from another remote-tracking branch, and so on?

Comment: @RandomDSdevel no, definitely not. Submodules might do something close to what you want, but probably not that either.

Comment: Can you update your answer to clarify this so that I can mark it as the answer to my original question?